# Как округлить число по разрядам?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

У меня есть два input, где value могут быть 1 233 323 и 14 987 322 (цены в миллионах). Задача округлять и выводить только разряды миллинов, т.е. 1 млн и 14 млн в данном случае.

Пишу так:

HTML:

```
<p>
<label for="mse2_ms|price_0">
<span>От</span>
<input id="mse2_ms|price_0" type="input" value="2673990" name="ms|price">
</label>
<label for="mse2_ms|price_1">
<span>До</span>
<input id="mse2_ms|price_1" type="input" value="3483545" name="ms|price">
</label>
<span>Млн. руб.</span>
</p>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.mfilter-price').val($('.mfilter-price input').val().substring(0, 1));
```

При этом с данным html во всех инпутах пишется 2.
Не могу понять, как для каждого уникально value менять.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) чтобы применить ф-ю ко всем отловленным элементам:

```
$( 'input[name="ms|price"]').each( function ( i, el) {
    $( el).val(
        Math.floor(     // округляем до целого, не превосходящего значение
                        // возможно, стоит округлять до ближайшего: Math.round()
            parseInt(   // парсим значение как целое число
                $(el).val().replace( /\s+/g, "") // убираем пробелы из значения, если есть
            ) / 1E6     // нужны миллионы – делим на миллион
        )
    );
});
```

[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/enrgk3kt/1/).

P.s. ничего нового не написал, просто оформил отдельным ответом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Всё работает как швейцарские часы. Не посчитайте за наглость, а как постоянно отслеживать input`ы? Дело в том, что под ними у меня еще и слайдер-бегунок, где эти интервалы меняются и при их перетаскивании цены возвращаются к миллионам с точностью до рубля (кстати, пробелы - это я просто в вопросе поставил, чтобы визуально понятнее было)

Comment: Слайдер наверняка телеграфирует свои события при движении – найдите его документацию. Логичнее слушать его события, и по ним обновлять значение;  нежели слушать изменения значений.

Answer (score 0):

Как вам такой вариант:

```
'14 434 434'.split(' ').length === 3 ? '14 434 434'.split(' ')[0]:false
```

Попробуйте в консоли :) Ну а если серьёзно:

```
function roundToM(t){
     var _t = t.split(' ');
     if (_t===3) { return _t[0]; }
     else { return false; }
}
```

Comment: @Олег Б, вы забыли в условии **_t.length** и значения value, я наблюдаю без пробелов. Если всё-таки это так, то изменить ваш код можно таким макаром: 

    function roundToM(t){
         var parts = t.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})*$)/);
         if (parts.length == 3) { return parts[0]; }
         else { return false; }
    }

Comment: Автор вроде пишет `где value могут быть 1 233 323 и 14 987 322`, если бы value было без пробела, можно тогда просто разделить на миллион, и воспользоваться `round`, что-то типа `Math.round(14355600/1000000)`

Comment: @Олег Б, Автор вроде пишет... и так, и так: в описании с пробелами, в коде - без. Поэтому, пусть сам автор и решит. И по второму, к примеру:

    console.log( Math.round(14555600/1000000) ); // 15, а не 14

Comment: тогда Math.floor(); :)

Comment: @Олег Б, это уже ближе к правде ツ

Comment: Оу, усложнили задачу))) Без пробелов. Просто выводить миллионы без остальных разрядов.

Comment: @Роман Жуков, если уверены, что миллионы будут всегда, то:

    $('input').each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).val( Math.floor($(el).val() / 1000000) );
    });

Еслемент с классом ".mfilter-price" я у вас не увидел, посему написал просто "input"